# comparing datasets for matching elements in a column

Tags: python, pandas

Recently attended an introduction into python/pandas and data sets.Now trying to put some of what I learned into use. Have trawled through various answers and tried various solutions with no luck.
Basically I wish to compare DF1 name with DF2 name and then add the scores together if I get a match. Example below

DF1

```
name score
fred  20
harry 30
joe   24
jim   14
```

DF2

```
name score
harry 25
joe   52
fred  61
jim   23
```

DF3

```
name score
fred   81
harry  55
jim    77
joe    76
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for both dataframes, then add them and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df3 = (df1.set_index('name') + df2.set_index('name')).reset_index()

In [77]: df3
Out[77]: 
    name  score
0   fred     81
1  harry     55
2    jim     37
3    joe     76
```